# Attributes difference in inherited classes properties

Tags: c#

I have two classes: `Element` and `Display`.

Now both classes have many common properties, so I consider to inherit from a base class.

Now comes the problem. For serialization the `Element` class should have `[XmlIgnore]` before each of this properties, but the `Display` class not.

How can I handle that?

Old:

```
public class Element
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set }
}

public class Display
{
    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set }
}
```

New:

```
public class DispBase
{
    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}

public class Element : DispBase
{
    // what to write here, to achieve XmlIgnore and Browsable(false)?
}

public class Display : DispBase
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the base class and properties  abstract and set the attributes per derived class where required:

```
public abstract class DispBase
{
    public abstract Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}

public class Element : DispBase
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public override Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}

public class Display : DispBase
{
    public override Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XmlAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and set XmlIgnore dynamically.

Sample classes:

```
public class Brush { }

public class DispBase
{
    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}

public class Element : DispBase { }
public class Display : DispBase { }
```

Example code:

```
var element = new Element { BackgroundBrush = new Brush() };
var display = new Display { BackgroundBrush = new Brush() };

using (var fs = new FileStream("test1.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    var attributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };

    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(typeof(DispBase), "BackgroundBrush", attributes);

    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Element), overrides);
    ser.Serialize(fs, element);
}

using (var fs = new FileStream("test2.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Display));
    ser.Serialize(fs, display);
}
```

Comment: This is more the way I think of how to do it.